# Rails 4 using multiple association to generate a filtered association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a interesting association in Rails 4.1 I am trying design and can't seem to come up with the right way to do it, so thought I would ask for help.

Essentially, we have four models that matter: **Family**, **ActivityTemplate**, **Device** and **DeviceType**. A Family has many Devices, Device belongs_to a DeviceType, and ActivityTemplates has_and_belongs_to_many DeviceTypes (think: these device types are supported in this activity).  The 5th model is our **FamilyActivity** which belongs_to Family and ActivtyTemplate.

What I am trying to do is get the list of **familyActivityInstance.available_devices** that are available. Or, stated another way, we know what DeviceTypes are capable of being used in a FamilyActivity based on the Family.devices->DeviceType association, AND, we know the activity supports only certain device types through its FamilyActivity.activity_template->DeviceType association, so we want to deliver a list of the subset of Family.devices that are included in BOTH device type association lists.

***Ideally, we'd like to call FamilyActivity.available_devices to get that list.  We can brute force this by iterating through the devices and comparing device types, but surely there is a better way!***

Here are the models just for reference:

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device_type
  belongs_to :family
end

class DeviceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :family_activities
end

class FamilyActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family
  belongs_to :activity_template
end

class ActivityTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :device_types
  has_many :family_activities, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your existing associations:

```
class DeviceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices
end

class FamilyActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :device_types, to: :activity_template

  def available_devices
    device_ids = \
      device_types.
      joins(:devices).
      where(devices: {family_id: self.family_id}).
      pluck("DISTINCT devices.id")

    Device.where(id: device_ids)
  end
end
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but I can't seem to get all the way there.  When run as written you get `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'activity_template' was not found on Device; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: My mistake. The `joins` was being applied to `Device` rather than `FamilyActivity`. The quickest solution I can offer now is via an instance method that returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. I believe that for your purpose this should be sufficient. (I've edited my response).

Comment: That is a great answer and works perfectly!  Thank you so much @humza

Comment: Actually... that returns the DEVICE TYPES, not the actual devices. but here is a query that gives me the actual devices.  Are there ways to optimize it?  

`family.devices.where(:device_type_id => self.activity_template.device_types.map(&:id))`

Comment: Yeah. You need to use `pluck` instead of `map`. I've updated my answer again.